# Cannot set IndexPath row in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

The following code produces a runtime error and I can't figure out how.  Any thoughts?

```
    var foo: IndexPath
    foo = IndexPath()
    foo.row = 1

    var i = 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preCondition in swift to access row of `indexpath`

```
/// The section of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
///
/// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
public var section: Int

/// The row of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
///
/// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
public var row: Int
```

[image]

If you want to access or change row you need to initialise indexPath with row and section

```
 var foo: IndexPath
 foo = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
 foo.row = 1 // return foo (1,0)
```

Comment: How were you able to step into the IndexPath source?  When I try to step in I don't get the nice source view that you get.

Comment: when I do that, I just get assembly code: libswiftUIKit.dylib`merged (extension in UIKit):Foundation.IndexPath.section.setter : Swift.Int:
    0x1022b22c0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x1022b22c1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp